# How can I delete a contact which was associated with a customer portal user?

Tags: community, customer-portal, user, user-management, delete

When I try to delete a contact I get the error:

Your attempt to delete CONTACT NAME could not be completed because it is associated with the following portal users

When I click into the portal user which is reported, I see that "Customer Portal User" is checked, and they have a "Customer" role and profile, but there's no delete option, and they are not currently marked as Active.

When i go to the contact record and use the "Manage External User" drop down - I only get "View Customer User" - no option to disable.

My user is an SA on this org.

Please let me know what you think - or any other information which I could provide to be helpful?

Thanks in advance!

Shamir

Comment: I believe all you can do is deactivate the user associated with the contact.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just to add to @John Thompson's answer, you can add the button that disables the customer user:

[image]

This will remove the connection between the user and the contact, and mark the user as deleted.
If you don't have this button - you can add it to your layout from the page layout editor:

[image]

After removing the connection between the contact and the user you can delete the contact without any problem.

Answer (score 3):

Once a User record is created in Salesforce it can't be deleted. This applies to *all* User license types, including Portal and Community Users.

The reason User records can't be deleted almost certainly has to do with event logs. All transactions in Salesforce (including login) have a reference to the User. If the User reference is no longer there, you have a *broken* event log record.

Portal and Community Users both have a dependancy on a Contact record.... You can't have the User without the Contact. As such, you won't be able to delete that Contact record now either.

In addition to deactivating the Portal/Community User from the (inexorably linked) Contact detail page, you can also deactivate the User from the User detail page by unchecking the "Active" checkbox as illustrated. I'll wager that's why there isn't a deactivate option on the Contact detail page.

[image: Portal User Detail page]

Answer (score 3):

Through code you can also acheive this. In developer console execute below code:

```
User u=[select id,Name, IsPortalEnabled from user where id='xyz' limit 1];
u.IsPortalEnabled=false;
update u;
```