# Inaccessible Contact on Partner user blocks everything on the User

Tags: partner-communities, user-management

something happend in our org that I've never seen before and that shouldn't be possible.

We have a user with a "Partner Community Login" license, that cannot be edited anymore.
I don't know what our user managers did, but the contact does not exist anymore, it shows as a underscore and clicking on the link gives me:

```
The requested resource does not exist
```

I can query the ContactId on the user record, but if I query for the ContactId on the Contacts, it doesn't return any results, even with ALL ROWS.

When editing or trying to disable the User (in LEX), even using apex or the console, I get redirected to the classic interface with following message:

```
Unable to Finish Processing Request
An error has occurred while processing your request. ...contact Salesforce support
```

And it does not save.

I already created a Case but I haven't gotten a reply yet (1 month) so I'm hoping, that maybe someone can help me with this, has anyone seen something like that or know how to fix this?

Kind regards

Comment: One of your internal users might have disabled the user for that contact and later on deleted the record. The user record can't be deleted and it will keep the reference to the original contact, I suppose. See: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/150221/how-can-i-delete-a-contact-which-was-associated-with-a-customer-portal-user